# Auth URI Rederects for Facebook doesn't work with Github Codespaces

Tags: facebook, github, facebook-graph-api, github-codespaces, railway

I was using Meta Graph API. In its authentication workflow, it needs a redirect uri. As I am devloping in github codespaces, when I put the redirected port of github codespaces as Whitelisted URLs. It still keeps on showing error in auth flow.

How to develop while working in auth flows. And how to test other parts of the app while bypasing authflows.

- I tried to work in github codespaces but redirect flows over the ported urls isn't working.
- I also tried to work localy but celery[redis] doesnt work in windows.
- I also tried dockerize it and put in railway. Railway doesnt show logs of docker and has no way to ssh into contaiers
- I also tried cloud9 but could not expose the port to preview the website in cloud9
- I also tried ubuntu@wsl but celery[redis] didnt work.
- I was goning to dual boot ubuntu but don't have disk space to try it atm.

Comment: What error are you getting?